# Visual Studio 2012 - asp.net web site

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web

I dont know if I am just being stupid but I want to create a Web Site with asp.net.  I go to File->New->Web Site and in the options it has I do not have the option of creating a Web Site like I have seen in 2008 and 2010 editions.  There is the option of creating an Empty Web Site - which I do not want as I want it to come with all the configuartion settings and the deafult.aspx page.  There is also an option in the 4.0 Framework for creating a website (Razor 1 or 2) but these will not allow me to use C# and again dont come with the default.aspx page.

Am I missing a trick here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want go for

```
ASP .net web forms site
```